# pyTelegramBotAPI Можно ли сделать так, чтобы на кнопке было написано одно, а при нажатии она писала в чат другое

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Например, есть кнопка, на которой написано значение "1", но при нажатии на нее, в чат отправляется сообщение "1) 1". Возможно, есть какой-то дополнительный параметр для types.KeyboardButton?

Answer (score 0):

Об обычных кнопках [KeyboardButton](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#keyboardbutton), которые отображаются на клавиатуре под полем для ввода текста, в руководстве написано следующее:

> **Text** of the button. If none of the optional fields are used, it **will
> be sent as a message when the button is pressed**

Таким образом, стандартными средствами изменить отправляемый текст нельзя. Но можно попробовать перехватывать номера отправляемых сообщений и изменять их текст уже после отправки. Это может происходить настолько быстро, что пользователь не будет замечать подмены.

Еще есть [InlineKeyboardButton](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#inlinekeyboardbutton), которые отображаются на Inline клавиатуре под конкретным сообщением. И вы можете запрограммировать выполнение любого кода при нажатии на них, в том числе отправку определенного текста.